# Node.js Asynchronous File I/O

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm new to Node.js and recently learned about the `fs` module. I'm a little confused about asynchronous vs. synchronous file i/o.

Consider the following test:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

var txtfile = 'async.txt';
var buffer1 = Buffer(1024);
var buffer2 = '1234567890';

fs.appendFile(txtfile, buffer1, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err };
    console.log('appended buffer1');
});

fs.appendFile(txtfile, buffer2, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err };
    console.log('appended buffer2');
});
```

About half the time when I run this, it prints `appended buffer2` before `appended buffer1`. But when I open the text file, the data always appears to be in the right order - a bunch of garbage from `Buffer(1024)` followed by `1234567890`. I would have expected the reverse or a jumbled mess.

What's going on here? Am I doing something wrong? Is there some kind of lower-level i/o queue that maintains order?

I've seen some talk about filesystem i/o differences with Node; I'm on a Mac if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding, although the code is asynchronous, at the OS level, the file I/O operations of the SAME file are not.  That means only one file I/O operation is processing at a time to a single file.

During the 1st append is occurring, the file is locked. Although the 2nd append has been processed, the file I/O part of it is put in the queue by the OS and finishes with no error status.  My guess is the OS does some checks to make sure the write operation will be successful such as file exists, is writable, and diskspace is large enough, and etc.  If all those conditions met, the OS returns to the application with no error status and will finish the writing operation later when possible.  Since the buffer of the 2nd append is much smaller, it might finish processing (not writing to file part of it) before first append finished writing to file.  You, therefore, saw the 2nd console.log() first.